# Wieder Panic in the number sequence

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

Find the next term of the following 2 Series:-

- $A. (3,5,11,17,31,41,59,__)$
- $B. (1,1,1,2,5,21,233,__)$

Hint:-

> The two series are related to each other.If you find the answer to one of the number sequence, the other will soon follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Series could be [A006450 or A175247](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C5%2C11%2C17%2C31%2C41%2C59&sort=&language=&go=Search) (*Primes with noncomposite subscripts.*)

In spite of the type of the series, the answer becomes

> **67**.

And the second one [A007570](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C21%2C233&sort=&language=&go=Search) = $F(F(n))$ where F is a Fibonacci number.

so the answer becomes

> **10946**

And there is no relation that I have found between these.

Comment: @Roby5 anyone can find the relation and explain it like they found without using any web site. The series that you need to ask should not be found by using any website.

Comment: Which website did you use?

Comment: The relation is that each sequence comes from a simple sequence applied twice. One is $p_{p_n}$ (the prime-numbered primes) and the other is $F_{F_n}$ (the Fibonacci-numbered Fibonacci numbers).